# Ask a user to change password (not mandatory action but desirable)

Tags: password

I'd like to know ways to encourage users to take action and change their password, specially those where security could be compromised (eg. 123456, 1234, abc123, etc). *From now on these combinations will be banned.*

I came up with different alternatives: email notification, dashboard notification and also a message in the Settings area with the Change your password option highlighted (eg. with a text alert).

It's not a mandatory request so I believe that a good and persuasive communication will play a key role. The point behind this is to persuade the user in order to take action, but not sounding like this: "Hey! Your password is insecure, change it." or "Your password is 1234, change it".

Comment: Except when they log in, you shouldn't be able to tell what your user's passwords are. In the event you're checking when they log in, you could present a 'change your password' page before they move on to wherever else they want to go. If it's not mandatory, provide a 'skip this step' link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users tend to avoid "work", and the set of users with these insecure passwords are probably using them because it was too much work to fill in the original registration screen with anything other than the bare minimum.

After registration, does this user care enough to go back and change their password? Will this type of user also ignore emails and prompts that require "work" on their part? Quite probably.

I would suggest that you put the change password as a login step so, immediately after they log in, they see the 2 fields (new password, and re-enter password) and pretty much nothing else. You can put a skip button there to keep it optional, but be as sneaky as you dare in positioning it. Ideally you want to make it harder work to find than just filling in the fields. Hopefully these users will take the path of least resistance and just change their password.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of critical security problems with what you've described.  First, because you're asking this question, it means you can actually see your users' passwords, which means you're keeping those passwords in your database in cleartext, not encrypted.  That's a serious security risk, because if someone hacks your site, they'll learn your users' passwords; or a rogue sysadmin can steal your database.  And as we know, people tend to reuse passwords and IDs on multiple sites.  If someone uses the same email and password combination on your site as they do on their personal banking site, they might sue you for negligence. (Several high profile password hacking news stories should provide you with motivation to fix this problem.)

So you really need to address your security problems before you start asking users to change passwords.  It's going to be a bit of work, but getting hacked will destroy a lot of trust and can even mean the end of your business.

1. **Time for a new security model.**

   Your new approach will need a more robust security model.  Consider adding some administrative state attributes to each account, where you can set values like "require password change at next logon", "account active/inactive", "last logon date", "password scheme v1/v2/v3", etc. Don't expose these to your users, of course.  You'll likely need an additional column for your new, securely stored passwords.  And if you've ever considered Role Based Access Control (RBAC), this may be the time to look again.
2. **Help your users.**

   In the new password screens, it's not uncommon to have client-side javascript that will dynamically 'rate' the passwords on a meter as they enter them:  "too weak, weak, medium, strong".  Put a red-line on the meter between 'too weak' and 'weak', and if they click the "change" button while their password is too weak, refuse to proceed until they choose a stronger password.  Be sure the javascript error tells them your policy and how they've not yet met it: "Password too short.  Passwords must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least one upper case letter, and either one symbol or one digit." Obviously you can set whatever rules you wish, but the more complex you make it the more confused your users will be.  And for security reasons, never send the partial password info back to your site.  Only send the change request after the users clicks 'change' and the javascript has passed your rules.
3. **Protect your users and yourself.**

   Convert your password storage to use a cryptographically strong solution, such as PBKDF2.  That will help prevent you and your admins from accidentally seeing your users passwords; it will also keep hackers from stealing them.  Note that this means you should only enforce the password strength rules during new password entry - current users with old passwords still need to log in to be able to change them!
4. **Consider other problems.**

   Adding real password security makes the forgotten password problem harder.  You can no longer send them an email with their old password, because you don't know it anymore.  Common approaches include "password hints", "answer 3 security questions (mother's maiden name, etc)", or "email me a link to reset my password."  I personally prefer the email approach, but you'll have to figure that out for yourself and your users.
5. **To outsource, or not to outsource.**

   Since all this is a lot of detailed technical work that's easy to get horribly wrong, consider changing over to a federated login service using OAuth 2.0, and allow your users to use their Facebook, Yahoo, Live, or Google accounts to log in.  That way you're not even seeing their passwords, so you don't have to worry about the users' poor password choices, how to reset passwords, or hackers stealing passwords.
6. **Test, and act on feedback.**

   Test it out by setting the "need to change" flags on some accounts with recent activity.  As your customers return, put up an interstitial that explains that you've improved your security and are requiring them to enter a new password.  You can contact them via email, but don't include links in bulk email that offer to directly change passwords; people have been taught to suspect phishing attacks from email links, and as you're improving your security, you really want to look secure to everyone.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easier for users to change and use passwords :

- Add a shortcut next to the notifications that will take them directly to the change password screen
- Add a password generator at the change password screen, so that users do not have to figure out a new password
- The password generator must produce strong passwords that are easy to remember
- Give them an easy way to retrieve their passwords, if they forget it